# Best synonyms for "expanding / enlarging the Knowledge / Science / Wisdom"

Tags: synonyms, archaicisms

I'm trying to invent the inscription to joke "certificates" which I'm going to send to some users of my site. Currently I come to:

```
By this we, brethren of CodeAbbey,
solemnly and unanimously inaugurate
(some name here)
the rank of Bishop, in recognition of devotedness and talent
proved by solving 125 programming problems
thus consecrating efforts to expand
Knowledge and Wisdom
```

However I'm not quite satisfied by "expanding Knowledge and Wisdom" - could you please suggest more "solemn" (and probably archaic) synonyms?

BTW if you see there are some horrible mistakes, please let me know?

And also - is there any way to replace `brethren` with something gender-neutral (`members` looks bit too dull, though perhaps I should use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could side-step by alluding to knowledge and wisdom rather than calling them out specifically:

"efforts to unravel The Infinite, and decode The Cryptic"

That sounds nicely archaic as well as containing a sly reference to the nature of your community.

Comment: I like this idea! Some of my clumsy attempts look like "consecrating toils to pave the roads of the Wonderbeautiful Unknown" - but I could not decide how stupid this sounds... and how to fix it. **UPD** I think I should instead borrow your `unravel the Infinite` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the term "enlightenment" as in:

```
thus consecrating efforts to expand
our enlightenment.
```

Also, the first line might read better if it were changed to

```
By this document, we the brethren of CodeAbbey,
```

Or maybe just as

```
We the brethren of CodeAbbey,
```

If you don't want to use "brethren", how about "fellows"?

```
We the fellows of CodeAbbey,
```

Comment: Wow, that is great! Moreover that I use `enlightenment` somewhere on the site. By the way, could I substitute `the brethren` with `fellowship` - or this is wrong in the context of `Abbey`?

Comment: @RodionGorkovenko: A fellowship has members, so you would probably have to use *"We the members of the fellowship of..."* Or just *"The fellowship of..."*

Comment: Ah, I see this will be bit too verbose, so your idea with `the fellows` looks better. I want to use `brethren` but also want to avoid offending female users in some way...

Comment: @RodionGorkovenko: You could use the word "siblings" which would include males and females, but I don't think it would have been normal to use it in this context, and I can't think of a gender-neutral word that conveys the same meaning.

Comment: Ah yes, I mostly have seen `siblings` in technical contest. Would `we, the brethren and sistren` look ok, or I should prepend `the` to both of them? **UPD** no, it looks only worse. I'll take `Fellows` :)